# properly zooming in scrollview with 3 imageviews

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, zooming

I'm having a scrollview containing view. In view there is 3 imageViews (screen sized).
At anytime user stands on second imageview.
I want to let user to zoom this imageview.

How to properly implement zooming in my situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to this tutorial , hope it helps :)

[how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content)

Answer (score 0):

you can set scrollview Maximum and Minimum zoom scale like bellow..

on your second page on second image just set your scrollview with maximumzoomscale property...

```
    CGFloat minScale = MIN(yourScrollView.frame.size.width, yourScrollView.frame.size.height);

   yourScrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale; 

    yourScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0f; /// set here your zoom scale...
    yourScrollView.zoomScale = minScale;
```

**UPDATE**

```
// Get a zoom scale that's zoomed in slightly, capped at the maximum zoom scale specified by the scroll view
CGFloat newZoomScale = yourScrollView.zoomScale * 1.5f;
newZoomScale = MIN(newZoomScale, yourScrollView.maximumZoomScale);

// Figure out the rect we want to zoom to, then zoom to it
CGSize scrollViewSize = yourScrollView.bounds.size;

CGFloat w = scrollViewSize.width / newZoomScale;
CGFloat h = scrollViewSize.height / newZoomScale;
CGFloat x = yourScrollView.center.x - (w / 2.0f);
CGFloat y = yourScrollView.center.y - (h / 2.0f);

CGRect rectToZoomTo = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);

[yourScrollView zoomToRect:rectToZoomTo animated:YES];
```

i hope this help you...

Comment: @kushtibargo see update with your requirement this code directly zoom the image with give zoom scale from the code see the code and for more info see this tutorial and get Demo.. http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content